# android separating a text file

Tags: android, text-files

I've been researching about how diablo 2 dynamically generates loot, and I thought it'd be fun to create a fun app that will randomly generate items using this system.

I currently have code which I believe should read the entire txt file, but it's not parsed.

It looks like:

```
private void itemGenerator() {
        int ch;
        StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
        InputStream fs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.treasureclass);
        // read file until end and put into strContent
        try {
            while((ch = fs.read()) != -1){
                strContent.append((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

An example in the text file would look something like:

```
Treasure Class  Item1   Item2   Item3
tc:armo3    Quilted_Armor   Buckler Leather_Armor
tc:armo60a  Embossed_Plate  Sun_Spirit  Fury_Visor
tc:armo60b  Sacred_Rondache Mage_Plate  Diadem
```

So what I'm thinking right now is putting each row into an array with `StringTokenizer` delimited by \n to get each row.  Then somehow do it again with tab-delimited for each item in the array and put it into a 2D array?

I haven't coded it yet because I think there's a better way to implement this that I haven't been able to find, and was hoping for some helpful input on the matter.

For anyone actually interested in knowing how the item generation works, their wiki page, http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Item_Generation_Tutorial, goes very in-depth!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing problem in distinguishing between each lines that are read-out from file. In order to read the file line-by-line you should change your code as below:

```
InputStream fs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.treasureclass);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    Log.i("line", line);
    //split the content of 'line' and save them in your desired way
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for that fix.  I'm still hung up on storing the data afterwards though.  So I can split each line delimited by tabs, then I suppose I can put it into a 2D array array2d[x][y] where [x] is the first column and [y] are the other 3 items?  The way to read the text file is to get a name from the first column, and then randomly pick one of the three items in that row.  If the item starts with "tc" (although in the sample none of them do), you search the first column for that name, until you reach an item that does not start with "tc".  With that information, does my idea seem to make sens

Comment: Yes, once you read-out the lines then you may manipulate it in any way you want. However, if your text files are large in size then I will not recommend you to use arrays as it may cause OutOfMemory issues depending on the device(s) your code executes. To avoid that, I would suggest you to make use of sqlite database